# Calling a method of a abstract class inside of a linked list fails

Tags: c++, arduino, abstract-methods

I wrote a Class called cube which holds a double linked list which should hold objects of a abstract class called `Animation` and has a method to add animations . It looks liket his:

```
class CubeLib
{
protected:
//some more variables 
    LinkedList<Animation*> animations; //a list of animations
public:
    inline void addAnimation(Animation* a){
        animations.add(a);
    };
}
```

The interface:

```
class Animation
{
 public:
    virtual void update(short delta) = 0; 
};
```

Inside of the ino of the arduino project i init the CubeLib and the Animation in global  and inside of the setup i add them to the list:

```
CubeLib cube;
Sinus* sinus_ani =new Sinus(&cube); // if not like this it stucks at setup?!
void setup()
{
    cube.addAnimation(sinus_ani);
}
```

Inside of a method called render i call the current Animations update function.

```
inline void CubeLib::update(short delta)
{
    if (animations.size() != -1){ //if its not empty
        animations[current_Animation]->update(delta);
    }
}
```

But in this case it does happen nothing. The update of the Sinus does not get called.
Last but not least here is my double linked list. (I tested it but maybe there is some issue with it?)

```
template <typename T>
class LinkedList
{
protected:
private:
    struct Node
    {
        Node* prev;
        Node* next;
        T value;
    };

    Node* last;
    Node* first;
    byte count;

public:
    LinkedList()
    {
        count = -1; //empty
    };

    ~LinkedList()
    {
        if (count > -1){
            clear();
        }
    };
    /** adds to list*/
    inline void add(T t);

    /**removes the thing at index*/
    inline T remove(int index);

    /** Returns NULL(ptr) if index is out of range or item not found somehow*/
    inline T get(int index);

    inline void clear();

    /**Returns the first obj*/
    inline T getFirst();

    /**Returns the last obj*/
    inline T getLast();

    /**Returns the current size. If -1 its empty!*/
    inline int size(){
        return count;
    };

    T operator[](const int i)
    {
        return get(i);
    };
};

template <typename T>
inline void LinkedList<T>::add(T t){
    Node* n = new Node();
    n->value = t;
    if (count > -1)
    {
        n->next = first;
        n->prev = last;
        last->next = n;
        last = n;
        count++;
    }
    else if (count == -1)//first element
    {
        first = n;
        first->next = n;
        first->prev = n;
        last = n;
        last->next = n;
        last->prev = n;
        count++;
    }
}

template <typename T>
inline T LinkedList<T>::remove(int index){
    if (index <= count)
    {
        Node* n = last;
        for (int i = 0; i <= index; i++)
        {
            n = n->next;
        }
        n->prev->next = n->next;
        n->next->prev = n->prev;
        count--;
        return n->value; //return the value of that node
    }
}

template <typename T>
inline T LinkedList<T>::get(int index){
    if (index <= count && index > -1)
    {
        Node* n = first;
        int i = 0;
        while (i < index)
        {
            n = n->next;
            i++;
        }
        return n->value;
    }
    return NULL;
}

template <typename T>
inline void LinkedList<T>::clear()
{
    Node* n = first;
    while (count > 0)
    {
        Node* toBeDeleted = n;
        n = n->next;
        delete toBeDeleted;
        count--;
    }
}
/**Returns the first obj*/
template <typename T>
inline T LinkedList<T>::getFirst()
{
    return first->value;
};

/**Returns the last obj*/
template <typename T>
inline T LinkedList<T>::getLast()
{
    return last->value;
};
```

I am sorry for alot of code here. And I hope its not a obvious failer.

---

Edit:

Sinus is declared liket his:

```
class Sinus : public Animation
{
private:
    RGB color;
    CubeLib* cube;
    byte colorcounter;
    float time;

public:
    Sinus(CubeLib* c) : time(0.0), colorcounter(0), cube(c){
        color.r = MAX_COLOR;
        color.g = MAX_COLOR;
        color.b = MAX_COLOR;
    };
    ~Sinus(){};
    void update(short delta);
};

void Sinus::update(short delta)
{
    //do this 1000 times
    time += (((float)delta)/1000.0);
    for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
    {
        float value = (2.0*sin((float)(x + 1)*time*12.0)) + 2.0;
        for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++)
        {
            for (int z = 0; z < 5; z++)
            {
                if (abs(((float)z) - value) < 0.5)
                {
                    //cube.setLED(x, y, z, depth - 30/5*(int)abs(z-value), 0, 0);
                    cube->setLED(x, y, z, color);
                }
                else
                {
                    cube->setLED(x, y, z, 0, 0, 0);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    colorcounter++;
    if (colorcounter > 25)
    {
        color.r = random(MAX_COLOR);
        color.g = random(MAX_COLOR);
        color.b = random(MAX_COLOR);
        colorcounter = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `current_Animation` equal to? Isn't `CubeLib::update()` supposed to call `update()` for all animations, not only one? Also make `Animation` destructor virtual

Comment: Why are you creating your own `LinkedList` class instead of just using `std::list<>`?

Comment: It's for arduino. Not sure if the std list works so I wrote my own. The current animations is the animation which is allowed todo something and get changed from time to time to other values depending on a fixed delay. The update itself get called inside of the loop and it does get called but the sin class update does not get any call.

Comment: Show us the definition of `Sinus` (add a link?)

Comment: Will add the sinus in ~1h (not at home). Will write a comment to indicate the edit.

Comment: @BennX I asking for the declaration of the constructor, you wrote this comment: `if not like this it stucks at setup?!` but this may be important for answering.

Comment: Well i tried doing it without a ptr like the cube declaration above but if I do so the arduino stuck inside of the setup method. (Tried by printing at the end of the setup. it calls the setup in a loop)

Comment: added sinus definition.

Comment: I check where the issue happens and its in the line where i do `animations[current_Animation]->update(delta);`this seems to cause an error so the arduino resets but i cant figure out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is really really really small and i noticed it just by luck.

I changed the counter of the list to byte to reduce the steps. But if my list is empty it is -1 so this would not work. Thats all! changed the count to short type and it works!

```
template <typename T>
class LinkedList
{
private:
    struct Node
    {
        Node* prev;
        Node* next;
        T value;
    };

    Node* last;
    Node* first;
    short count; // HERE 
/...
};
```

Comment: Possibly because by default byte is unsigned.  Since you assigned -1 to it, it will probably end up as 255.